# magento2 cli with docker

Tags: cli, docker

How do you run magento commands when using a docker container, like

```
php bin/magento setup:deploy
```

I have a docker container with php 7, mysql 5.6. The website works ok, but if I try to run some magento commands it tries to run them through the system php, which is 5.4.

It is more of a docker workflow question, as I'm unsure what to do next. I tried `docker exec 281cbd203f92 magento setup:upgrade` but obviously it doesn't recognize the magento command. Should I add it to the path in the container?

My container:

```
281cbd203f92        cloudwaysdocker/docker_debian   "/bin/bash /start.sh"   5 days ago          Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   magento2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can solve it by running Magento commands inside container.
You need to login into container first:

```
docker exec -ti 281cbd203f92 /bin/bash
```

After that you need to change current directory to document root of your Magento, add path to /bin/magento to container PATH variables like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/magento2/bin
```

After that you can run magento commands inside and outside container.